# Non-binary file versioning with WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

It seems that all binary files (.dll and .exe) defined in a WIX file inherit their version and language from the `Product` element. All other files (.ps1, .txt, etc) don't inherit the version and don't get replaced on upgrade. I need to be able to version non-binary files, so they can be overwritten on upgrade. Once I set [DefaultVersion](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_file.htm) on the file element, everything works fine and file gets replaced on upgrade.

```
<Component Id="Eula.txt" Guid="14285C13-A70C-474B-B2AE-06F68D4E170B">
   <File Id="Eula.txt" DiskId="1" Name="Eula.txt" Source="$(var.NeutralBinRoot)\" DefaultVersion="$(var.MsiProductVersion)"/>
</Component>
```

However, I get this warning during compilation:

```
warning LGHT1103 : The DefaultVersion '1.1.1' was used for file 'Eula.txt' which has no version. 
No entry for this file will be placed in the MsiFileHash table. 
For unversioned files, specifying a version that is different from the actual file may result in unexpected versioning behavior during a repair or while patching. 
Version the resource to eliminate this warning.
```

What is a proper way to version non-binary resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs it looks like you need to use the [CompanionFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_file.htm) attribute and link it back to the original assembly. I haven't used this myself so can't say 100% whether it'll work but worth a punt!

Comment: This is all very well if there is a companion file to link to. I am building an install kit for a product that consists of Access .MDE files. On the target machine each.MDE file will be updated by Access every time it is opened, regardless of whether it is changed. This would prevent it being replaced by a patch. The only way I could find to force the .MDE files to be replaced was by using DefaultVersion. It seems to work fine, but I do get the LGHT1103 warning, which I decided I just have to live with. If anyone does find a way of suppressing it I'd be interested to hear.